# How to feed the variable with end of lines to standard input of other application in bash?

Tags: bash, stdin, echo

Is there a (simple) way to feed variable with end of lines to other program in BASH? Consider example:

```
flist=$(ls -l)
echo $flist
```

`echo` will replace all end of lines with spaces, so my output will be different from the content of the variable. Other example:

```
echo $flist | grep myfile.txt
```

This command will not work as expected to output only information about `myfile.txt`. How do I print the line that contains `myfile.txt`.

---

Here is one solution:

```
cat << EOF | grep myfile.txt       
$flist
EOF
```

Anything less ugly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not `echo`, is the shell.
Try to use double quotes:

```
echo "$flist" | grep myfile.txt
```

Should work fine.